# how to allow a slash / in preg_match with php

Tags: php, input, preg-match

To filter input for only `a-z` , `A-Z` and `0-9` i use this line:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST['copyfile-destination'])
```

What do i have to change that a slash `/` is also allowed?

Comment: just escape it `\/`

Comment: where do i have to put `\/` this?

Comment: in square brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape it or use another delimiter (eg # instead of /)

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+$/', $_POST['copyfile-destination'])
```

or

```
preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9/]+$#', $_POST['copyfile-destination'])
```

Comment: Thnx. works fine